# PhoneGap 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY

Tags: facebook, cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-plugins

Using PhoneGap with VS 2015, trying to redirect to facebook for external user login to my app using

```
    window.location.assign(e.url);
```

have also tried InAppbrowser

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(e.url, '_self', 'location=no, toolbar=no');
```

Still getting error below

```
Refused to display
 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=***********&display=page' 
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try change '_self' to '_blank' ?